# removeEventListener is not working inside 'click' listener

Tags: javascript, listener

Im fairly new to javascript, i got this problem that i cannot fix, i cant remove click event listener and here is my code:

```
function humanClick(event) {

    const target = event.target
    const nodeId = target.id;
    BOARD[nodeId] = humanPlayer;
    target.innerHTML = humanPlayer;
    if (checkForWinner(BOARD) == null) {
        aiPlay(BOARD);
    };
    target.removeEventListener("click", humanClick);
```

```
// adding listeners
nodes.forEach(node => {
  node.innerText = null; 
  node.style.background = null; 
  node.addEventListener("click", humanClick);
});
```

Comment: where are you adding your event listener?

Comment: You need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `target` may not be the element the listener is attached to, instead use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget). `event.currentTarget.removeEventListener("click", humanClick);`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I tried what u just suggested @pilchard but still it didn't work, i don't get any errors but the click event listener is still activated. also i tried to console.log(target) its returning the right html element in the console.i have no clue what is the problem

Comment: Is it possible you've added multiple listeners? Are you sure you're only calling your add listeners loop once?